# django migrate: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, django, migrate

i write this model in models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and i run `python manage.py migrate` and receive this error

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, news, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  Applying auth.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 249, in apply_migration
    with self.connection.schema_editor(
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 39, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "/home/ilya/code/Project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 289, in check_constraints
    for column_name, (
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: python 3.10

Django 4.1

Comment: Did you run makemigrations first?